# Newrelic + node.js + socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, newrelic

Newrelic announced support for node.js applications on Oct 24, 2013.

I set up monitoring for my node.js server. It is a service that talks to Client via socket.io. Now, all the requests like this `/socket.io/*/xhr-polling/40pt1SBvasfDuwctz4Ma` for the service appear to take 20.000 seconds.

Is there a way to set up newrelic so it would correctly show request times served by socket.io?

Answer (score 14):

New Relic gives you the option to ignore a rule for something exactly like this. For example you would want to add something like the following:

```
// newrelic.js
exports.config = {
  // other configuration
  rules : {
    ignore : [
      '^/socket.io/.*/xhr-polling/.*'
    ]
  }
};
```

There is also an API call that you can use to programmatically do this. You can find more about this in the node.js agent github [README.md](https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic#rules-for-naming-and-ignoring-requests)

Comment: Is there a way to manually add monitoring, rather than just to ignore the path?

Answer (score 4):

The software is actually working as intended.

When using XHR-polling with Socket.IO, the default polling duration is 20 seconds. Therefore, the connection is held open for 20 seconds, which is the reason why New Relic reports it as so.