# Integrating NewRelic with SailsJS and SocketIO (web sockets)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js, newrelic

I've successfully integrated NewRelic into my Sails install, however only direct http calls to the api show up in the statistics on the NewRelic control panel. Internal calls made via the SocketIO interface dont seem to register(which are the vast bulk of the calls we make).
Has anyone got the web socket calls to show up inside NewRelic?

This is the code I am currently using inside my app.js

```
var newrelic = require('newrelic');
// Start sails and pass it command line arguments
require('sails').lift(require('optimist').argv);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that even if it works, it might not give you the results you expect.  See [Newrelic + node.js + socket.io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591611/newrelic-node-js-socket-io?rq=1) and [known Node.js NewRelic limitations](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/nodejs/known-nodejs-limitations).

Answer (score 2):

SocketIO, being session-based, presumes a very different performance model than transactional HTTP requests, which The New Relic Node.Js Agent specifically picks up. Using the Sails Framework you are frequently bypassing this type of request. Due to the fact that the Sails.js framework wraps http in socket requests, New Relic is unable to monitor these transactions at this point.

Comment: The OP states that he is making requests via sockets, and that those requests aren't showing up in NewRelic.  It's his choice to use sockets; it has nothing to do with the way Sails works.  HTTP requests to Sails from the client are not in any way "wrapped in socket requests".  You can use the Sails socket client to communicate with the backend using sockets--so doing `socket.get('/users')` will run the same backend code and return the same result as a jQuery `$.get('/users')`--but again, that's your choice.  The question is, why in the OP's case are these requests not being registered?